# Direction Array: reducing complexity

Tags: java, arrays

I have a m*n matrix where every element is unique. From a given starting point I have to move to the smallest point(up, down, left, right)and then have to do the same process again. When all other surrounding point is greater than the existing one I have to stop and print the position from start. suppose I have a matrix(5*5)

```
1  2  3  4  5
6  7  8  9  10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
```

and starting point is (2,2) then the output will be `13,8,3,2,1`.
I have solved this problem my way, But the problem is its complexity. I do not think my solution is efficient. Can anyone suggest me any better solution?

N.B: Except scanner pkg, I am not allowed to import any other pkg. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DirectionArray {
public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int row = in.nextInt();
        int col = in.nextInt();
        int[][] ara = new int[row][col];
        int[] ara2 = new int[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                ara[i][j] = in.nextInt();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Give starting point(x) ");
        int x= in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Give starting point(y) ");
        int y= in.nextInt();
        int sx=x;
        int sy =y;
        int [] fx={+1,-1,0,0};
        int [] fy={0,0,+1,-1};
        int p=0;
        int l=0;
        int v=0;
        int r=0;
        int [] result=new int[row*col] ;
        int min=ara[x][y];
        boolean swap=true;
        for(int i=0;i<(row*col)-1;i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                int nx = x + fx[k];
                int ny = y + fy[k];

                if (nx >= 0 && nx < row && ny >= 0 && ny < col) {
                    if (min > ara[nx][ny]) {

                        ara2[p] = ara[nx][ny];
                        p++;

                    }

                }
}
            p=0;
            while(swap) {
                swap=false;
                r++;

                for (int q = 0; q < ara2.length-r; q++) {
                    if(ara2[q]>ara2[q+1]){
                    int temp = ara2[q];
                        ara2[q]=ara2[q+1];
                        ara2[q+1]=temp;
                        swap=true;
                    }
                }
            }
          for(int j=0;j<ara2.length;j++) {
                    if(ara2[j]!=0)
                    {
                        v=ara2[j];
                        result[l]=v;
                        l++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                min=v;
            for(int o=0;o<ara2.length;o++) {
                ara2[o]=0;
            }
                for(int m=0;m<row;m++){
                    for(int n=0;n<col;n++){
                        if(ara[m][n]==v) {
                            x = m;
                            y = n;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: This question would be better placed on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to split up your code in more methods. It would make it easier to read.

For example this is how I would reorganize it:

```
private static final int[][] COORDINATES_TO_TRY = new int[][]{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, -1}};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int row = in.nextInt();
    int col = in.nextInt();
    int[][] array = new int[row][col];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            array[i][j] = in.nextInt();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Give starting point(x) ");
    int x = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Give starting point(y) ");
    int y = in.nextInt();
    findMinimum(array, x, y);
    return;
}

private static int[] findMinimum(int[][] array, int x, int y) {
    for (int i = 0; true; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            System.out.print(",");
        }
        System.out.print(array[x][y]);
        int[] coordinates = findLocalMinimum(array, x, y);
        if (x == coordinates[0] && y == coordinates[1]) {
            return coordinates;
        }
        x = coordinates[0];
        y = coordinates[1];
    }
}

private static int[] findLocalMinimum(int[][] array, int x, int y) {
    int min = array[x][y];
    int minX = x;
    int minY = y;
    for (int[] coordinates : COORDINATES_TO_TRY) {
        int i = x + coordinates[0];
        int j = y + coordinates[1];
        if (i >= 0 && i < array.length && j >= 0 && j < array[i].length) {
            if (array[i][j] < min) {
                minX = i;
                minY = j;
                min = array[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return new int[]{minX, minY};
}
```